# Disabling dark mode inside a framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this requirement that I need to build a particular UI Framework for iOS and wanted to see if it's possible to set UIUserInterfaceStyle within framework plist as "Light", but the higher-level order application can have both modes on?

Comment: Not explicitly but you could override all initializers of the views in your framework and set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light`.